# request call giving me TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the OneDrive API to checkout a file (locking it by making it read-only) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_checkout?view=odsp-graph-online

My `lockFile` function below calls this api, and successfully locks the file. The problem is that I'm getting an error right after the call: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined`

I've been stepping through this call with my debugger and the error is popping before I even try to call statusCode on the line below it. Looking at the OneDrive API, it says it only returns a `status: 204`. Could it be that the request package I'm using is expecting a `statusCode` somewhere under the hood? If so, how can I resolve this if I'm only getting a `status` back?

Also, while stepping through with my debugger I've noticed that the error pops up a second before I see the `response` returns and is set to `IncomingMessage`. I'm trying to look up docs explaining what that means, but I haven't been finding anything helpful.

```
lockFile(fileId, driveId, authorization, callback) {
       const call = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: authorization.meta.serviceEndpointUri + '/drives/' + driveId + '/items/' + fileId + '/checkout',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authorization.access_token
            }
        }

        request(call, (err, response, body) => {
            /////////////////
            //I'M GETTING THE ERROR RIGHT HERE, BEFORE IT GETS TO THE NEXT LINE
            /////////////////
            if (err || (response && response.statusCode !== 204)) {
                let statusCode = (response && response.statusCode) ? response.statusCode : 500;
                statusCode = (statusCode === 204) ? 500 : statusCode;//We don't want to send a 204 id there isn't the right data
                callback(StorageProviderError(this.name, statusCode, 1007, body));
            }

            return callback(null, response);
        
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment (NOOB), my guess without running the code is that you are returning the function before code inside the if statement is finished executing.

try adding an else block and put the return there. I typically surround things in a promise or at the least a try catch block.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. It does look like it was returning too soon. I couldn't tell from how my debugger was stepping through it and seemed like it was still processing. I changed the function that calls lockFile to use an await on the call, and changed lockFile to use a try/catch surrounded axios call instead of using request. Now it's waiting for it to complete. Your answer pointed me in the right direction, very much appreciated!